# Equality proportions test for a subset of categories of a categorical variable

Tags: r, tidymodels

The vignette of `infer` package gives examples to test equality for ALL categories but not for a SUBSET of the categories.

For example, in `infer::gss` dataset, is there a way to test for the `income` variable if the proportion of `$25000 or more` is equal to `20000-24999`?

Thank you

[R tidymodels/infer](https://github.com/tidymodels/infer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `filter` the levels of the 'income', remove the unused levels (`droplevels`) and use that in the test

```
library(dplyr)
library(infer)
gss %>% 
   filter(income %in% c("$20000 - 24999",  "$25000 or more" ) ) %>% 
   droplevels %>% 
   specify(response = income, success = "$20000 - 24999") %>% 
   hypothesize(null = "point", p = .5) %>%
   generate(reps = 1000) %>%
   calculate(stat = "prop")
```